# Enter 500k records Gets compile error expected user defined type not project

Tags: ms-access, module

```vb
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit ' forces programmer to declare variable before its used .

Sub array500K()

 'this subroutine enters 500K records into part of STAFF table.

 'declare variable by using keyword called DIM

Dim StaffNames() As Variant ' () = array.Array is always declared with Variant

 'Variant data type has all other datatypes included.

Dim addresses() As Variant, address1 As String

Dim num As Integer, dbs As Database, insertRecord As String

Dim staffID As Long, num1 As Long, StaffName As String

 'assign value to variables

Set dbs = CurrentDb() 'points at the current database.

staffID = 0 'intialise the value

StaffNames = Array("Peter", "Mary", "Frank", "Paul", "Ian", "Ron", "Natalie", "Radhu", "Jat", "David", 
"Michelle", "Melissa", "jessica", "Tony", _
"Tommy", "Tim", "Tom", "Nina", "Kate", "Kim", "jay", "Nga", "Vicki", "Alison", "Nancy", "Joe", "Brandon", "Katie", "Hong", _
"Lanh", "Kelvin", "Jason", "Andrew", "Peter", "Oliver", "Mark", "Luke", "Lucy", "Anthony", "David", "Micheal", "Jess", "Monica", "daniela", _
"Suzy", "Aneta", "Bill", "Trish", "Fred", "Bobby", "Kem", "Doan", "Danny", "Ane", "Micheala", "George", "Harrison", "Lisa", "Luch", "Steve", _
"Sonya", "Nawal", "Chris", "Frankie", "jason", "Meegan", "Stephanie", "Bianca", "Silvia", "Valeria", "Hassan", "Mohamed", "Abdi", "Malik", "Ayeen", "Yussuf", _
"Mustafa", "Amal", "Musa", "Said", "Aisha", "Omar", "Osman", "Abas", "Hani", "Iman", "Ahmed", "Muna", "Maryam", "Mousa", "John", "Helen", "Nikki", "Anastasia", _
"Authur", "Kathy", "Nick", "George", "Vicki", "Georgia", "Ingrid", "Kelly", "Elizabeth", "Jerry", "Phillip", "Mary", "Alex", _
"Nerma", "Lisa", "Gabby", "Beth", "Eva", "Daniella", "Jim", "James", "Rohan", "Johan", "Rajv", "Sunny", "Johanthan", "Hari", "Mithel", "Kingston", "Shanker", "Vijay", "Rishi", _
"Ajith", "David", "Petrie", "Neel", "Luky", "Robert", "King", "Steven", "Anthony", "Anthony", "Billy", "Shaun", "Briana", "Christina", "Mariah", "Nick", "Tim", "Trish", "John", _
"Jack", "James", "CLaudia", "Chantelle", "Rebecca", "Roger", "Felicia", "Sammy", "Patrick", "Olivia", "Cuong", "Khoa", "Kim", "Mat", "Raymond", "Jason", "Dennis", "Jimmy", "Michael", "Joe", _
"Vuthorn", "Ally", "Alex", "Vinh", "Sandra", "Jacky", "Vi", "Winston", "Robert", "Mary", "Diana", "Barbara", "George", "Ruby", "Henry", "Max", "Laura", "Nadia", "Anthony", "Frank", "Nathan", "Sarina", "Annalisa", "Nicholas", "David", "Angelo", "Jake", "Greg", "Murray", "Kathy", "Dani", "Anthony", "Eva", "Anglea", "Daniel", "Ben", "Sarah", "Nicholas", "Lana", _
"David", "Stefan", "Alexssandra", "Christan", "Cassandra", "Ryan", "Melissa", "Jenna", "Matthew", "James", "Micheal", "Dani", "Anthony", "Eva", "Anglea", "Daniel", "Ben", "Sarah", "Nicholas", "Lana", _
 "David", "Stefan", "Alexssandra", "Christan", "Cassandra", "Ryan", "Melissa", "Jenna", "Matthew", "James", "Micheal", "Linh", "Lily", "Linda", "Jose", "Clark", "Thomas", "Doughlas", "Kyla", "Daniel", "Eva", _
"Susanna", "Sandy", "Krystal", "Thuy", "Leon", "Tony", "Doonie", "Sela", "Scott", "Yasha")

addresses = Array("Lons", "CBD", "PK", "Glen", "Hopp", "Mal", "Cra", "Met", "FLin", "Dand")

 'run For loops enter about 10 records.

For num1 = 0 To 500

    staffID = staffID + 1

    'Equation for random generation.

    'Int ((upperbounf - lowerbound +1) * Rnd + lowerbound)

    num = Int((200 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)

    StaffName = StaffNames(num)

    num = Int((9 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)

    address1 = addresses(num)

    'Enter records into STAFF table by designing a STRING INSERT statement.

    insertRecord = "INSERT INTO Staff(StaffNo, StaffFName, Address) VALUES (" & _
    "'" & staffID & "'" & "," & "'" & StaffName & "'" & "," & "'" & address1 & "'" & ")"

    dbs.Execute insertRecord

    Debug.Print staffID, StaffName, address1

Next 'end of FOR statement 
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why randomized? That will allow duplicate combinations. If you want only unique pairs, then use nested loops that use array UBound property to control loop. The complete error message should be in question narrative. Which line triggers error? What is purpose of this code, just an exercise?

Comment: Yes, gustav. It's just for an exercise.The problem i got it's just the naming error, but i have fix it. i just wanted to put a 500 records into one of my table. I will try to used nested loops after this.Anyway Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the annoyingly **lazy** question, I'll be a professional and point you towards an answer. This is a [name collision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-conflicts-with-existing-module-project-or-object-library) problem. [ProjectName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/aa173217(v=office.11)) is the top level of your module hierarchy. It's absolutely **imperative** that no other variable or object in your database be declared (Dim keyword) with the [same name](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-for-naming-fields-controls-and-objects-120c27fa-7ae1-4182-9baa-dbd183179cc3).

### [image]

- 

To locate the colliding variable or object name, close all of your code windows and execute *Compile* from the *Debug* menu. Then change the offending variable or object name, or that of the project, and save and close the database. After reopening, recompile. Please use the links I've provided to improve upon your knowledge and skills. I see *very sloppy* variable and object naming habits in your code. Your code does run, by the way. I tested it.

[image]